# 2sxc: In app setting can't upload images

Tags: 2sxc

I need to set a default image for my new app, so I was thinking about to use the app setting feature.

So I added a new content type of file type, but trying to upload a 20,3 KB file from adam it gives me the following error

> The upload failed. The most likely cause is that the file you were trying to upload is bigger than the maximum upload size.

Using the image manager I'm able to upload my image and work with it.
It is an adam issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most likely it's a forbidden file extension. Check fiddler / network-trafic to see what the real error is.

Comment: I just checked this, I haven't a file filter, and even setting it to *.png I got the same error. Here is the fiddler header 'Request URL: http://www.baffirandagi.it/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/app-content/App-Settings/059facb3-0968-4021-92a7-72984522fcf2/Prova
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400
Form Data
------WebKitFormBoundaryRW7SXLVuaB031nDL Content-Disposition: form-data; name: "uploadfile"; filename="donna.png" Content-Type: image/png
Cookie (15) 920byte'

Comment: I just ran some tests and cannot reproduce your issue. Please try some more variations - like doing this on a normal content-item, on another app, etc.

Comment: I tryed with a new app and also with the 2sxc blog one, tomorrow I will try again and maybe I could do a screencast

Comment: Btw it does work uploading images with Adam in an edit context, for example adding a gallery... It just seems not working on the app setting context..

Comment: @GiovanniManzo could I test it? pls send me access data to info@2sxc.org

Comment: Maybe it was a cache problem, cause today I tryed again and it does work... :| Anyway I will send you access data to my environment test to test about the drag and drop module issue. Thanks